# Why is My RN Turbo Modules Package 'null'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-turbomodule

Following the Android Turbo Modules in the documentation [see here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/pillars-turbomodules) to a tee, I see the following error when I try to use it in my react-native code:

'Cannot read property 'add' of null, js engine: hermes'

I have fabric enabled and hermes enabled. I'm using RN 0.72.6. Does anyone experience the same thing when they go through the documented guide?

I was expecting to be able to use the package in my React Native app to perform an addition, but instead, the library was null.

What's interesting is that in both my CalculatorModule and CalculatorPackage files, I have an error :'Unresolved reference: facebook'

Please see the code below

Here's my folder structure:
[RTNCalculator folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTwtH.png)

CalculatorModule.kt

```
package com.rtncalculator

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.rtncalculator.NativeCalculatorSpec

class CalculatorModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : NativeCalculatorSpec(reactContext) {

  override fun getName() = NAME

  override fun add(a: Double, b: Double, promise: Promise) {
    promise.resolve(a + b)
  }

  companion object {
    const val NAME = "RTNCalculator"
  }
}
```

CalculatorPackage.kt

```
package com.rtncalculator;

import com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.module.model.ReactModuleInfo
import com.facebook.react.module.model.ReactModuleInfoProvider

class CalculatorPackage : TurboReactPackage() {
 override fun getModule(name: String?, reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): NativeModule? =
   if (name == CalculatorModule.NAME) {
     CalculatorModule(reactContext)
   } else {
     null
   }

 override fun getReactModuleInfoProvider() = ReactModuleInfoProvider {
   mapOf(
     CalculatorModule.NAME to ReactModuleInfo(
       CalculatorModule.NAME,
       CalculatorModule.NAME,
       false, // canOverrideExistingModule
       false, // needsEagerInit
       true, // hasConstants
       false, // isCxxModule
       true // isTurboModule
     )
   )
 }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext.safeExtGet = {prop, fallback ->
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
  }
  repositories {
    google()
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.22")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.facebook.react'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

android {
  compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 33)
  namespace "com.rtncalculator"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native'
}
```

js/NativeCalculator.ts

```
import type {TurboModule} from 'react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/RCTExport';
import {TurboModuleRegistry} from 'react-native';

export interface Spec extends TurboModule {
  add(a: number, b: number): Promise<number>;
}

export default TurboModuleRegistry.get<Spec>('RTNCalculator') as Spec | null;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rtn-calculator",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Add numbers with Turbo Native Modules",
  "react-native": "js/index",
  "source": "js/index",
  "files": [
    "js",
    "android",
    "ios",
    "rtn-calculator.podspec",
    "!android/build",
    "!ios/build",
    "!**/__tests__",
    "!**/__fixtures__",
    "!**/__mocks__"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "repository": "https://github.com/<your_github_handle>/rtn-calculator",
  "author": "<Your Name> <your_email@your_provider.com> (https://github.com/<your_github_handle>)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/<your_github_handle>/rtn-calculator/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/<your_github_handle>/rtn-calculator#readme",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*"
  },
  "codegenConfig": {
    "name": "RTNCalculatorSpec",
    "type": "modules",
    "jsSrcsDir": "js",
    "android": {
      "javaPackageName": "com.rtncalculator"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your actual code, it's going to be hard for people to help.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the post to include code

Comment: @temx2 Make sure you have followed all the steps properly, I just followed all the steps and I was able to get the result.

Comment: @VickyAhuja what RN version did you use? Would you happy to share your package files? Perhaps I could spot the difference

Comment: @temx2 react native : 0.72.6 version

Comment: @temx2 I just followed the link you given in your question.

Comment: @VickyAhuja I see. In what directory did you put your NativeCalculator.ts file?

Comment: @temx2 inside RTNCalculator/js